# How to seperate sentences in a dataframe based on last occurence of small letter followed by a capital one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe containing sentences. The first sentence (the title) is followed by the text. They were merged without a space.

I would like to slit the text into two parts (sentence 1 and sentence 2) based on the last occurence of a capital letter following a lowercase letter without a space in between (out of curiosity I would also be interested in a solution based on the first appearance).

The solution is supposed to be stored in the original dataframe.

I tried

```
re.findall('(?<!\s)[A-ZÄÖÜ](?:[a-zäöüß\s]|(?<=\s)[A-ZÄÖÜ])*')
```

but could not work it out.

```py
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

Sentences = {'Sentence': ['RnB music all nightI love going out','Example sentence with no meaningThe space is missing.','Third exampleAlso numbers 1.23 and signs -. should appear in column 2.', 'BestMusic tonightAt 12:00.']}

df = DataFrame(Sentences,columns= ['Sentence'])

print(df)
```

As the split is supposed to be carried out at the last occurrence. The words `RnB` and `BestMusic` in the example given are not supposed to trigger the split.

```py
df.Sentence1 = ['RnB music all night','Example sentence with no meaning','Third example', 'BestMusic tonight']

df.Sentence2 = ['I love going out','The space is missing.', 'Also numbers 1.23 and signs -. should appear in column 2.' ,'At 12:00.']
```

Comment: Try a for loop going to through each character to check if it is uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
Yourdf=df.Sentence.str.split(r'(.*[a-z])(?=[A-Z])',n=-1,expand=True)[[1,2]]
Yourdf
Out[610]: 
                                  1                                                  2
0               RnB music all night                                   I love going out
1  Example sentence with no meaning                              The space is missing.
2                     Third example  Also numbers 1.23 and signs -. should appear i...
3                 BestMusic tonight                                          At 12:00.
```

Comment: @NDel yw happy coding

Answer (score 1):

This only works if A-Z is all your capital letters:

```
pattern = r'(?P<Sentence1>.*)(?P<Sentence2>[A-Z].*)$'
df['Sentence'].str.extract(pattern)
```

gives:

```
    Sentence1                           Sentence2
0   RnB music all night                 I love going out
1   Example sentence with no meaning    The space is missing.
2   Third example                       Also numbers 1.23 and signs -. should appear i...
3   BestMusic tonight                   At 12:00.
```